# My Raspberry Pi3 shows no network access

Tags: raspbian, putty, xming

[image]

My Raspberry Pi 3 shows no network access
I tried with putty
but its showing
connection timed out

Answer (score 1):

Probably haven't enabled SSH on the Pi.

In a terminal on the Pi do a **sudo raspi-config** and under the "7 - Advanced" menu option check that SSH is actually enabled.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md

If it is, from that terminal window do a **sudo ifconfig** and confirm that the IP number is the one that you are actually trying to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to your modem's page(192.168.1.1) and check the DHCP clients so that you could see the raspberry pi's IP Address. Or try connecting with the hostname raspberrypi